# Solve Absolute Value Problem

Tags: logarithms, absolute-value

I tried to solve this problem, but so far I was only able to find that $x=1$ is a solution, the problem is
$$\left(|x-1|^{(\log_{10}x)^2}\right)-\left(\log_{10}x^2\right)=|x-1|^3$$

Comment: is the second $\log$also in the Exponent?

Comment: If $x=1$ then the first term is $0^0$ which is undefined.

Comment: No second log is not in the expotent

Comment: oh, 1 isn't a solution then

Comment: Numerically, I get $x ≈ 1.78402557095943...$ as the only solution, though I didn't check the computation carefully.

Comment: @lulu can you please tell me how did you get this solution?

Comment: Sure.  I typed your equation into wolfram alpha.  Given the complex nature of the equation, I'd want to check the answer...but that should be easy enough, no?  I'd think any numerical method would work...Newton or just a simple search.

Comment: I just checked the result, seems to work (both sides are $0.481937458$).